# Getting error on installing magento 2.2.4

Tags: installation, magento2.2.4

I am trying to install magento latest version 2.2.4. But I am facing

> **Fatal error:** Cannot use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface as
>   ConfigInterface because the name is already in use in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\magento224\vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Method\Logger.php**
>   on line **8**

Comment: Check your configuration settings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shubham, Use php version 7.1.17 in xampp. I hope your problem will be resolved.