# Cannot use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface as ConfigInterface because the name is already in use in module-payment\Model\Method\Logger.php

Tags: installation, magento2.2.4

Below error showing in php version 7.0.6 Installation time of magento version 2.2.4

```
Fatal error: Cannot use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface as ConfigInterface because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\m224\vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Method\Logger.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like Magento 2.2.4 bug, because in the current namespace the `ConfigInterface` already exists:

[image]

so fix should be made in the core files :( Try to report this on the github.

**Update:**

Here the fix for it https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/a7d4180ce61a7e9027befefac4ef4af6333ee8ff

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12180#issuecomment-372574834

Another way to fix this issue is to use PHP >= 7.1.

Source: [Getting error on installing magento 2.2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225909/getting-error-on-installing-magento-2-2-4/226005#226005)

Comment: There are more of these issues, so by now you should use a recent PHP version to solve it, i.e. 7.0.13 or higher. Note that I had the same issue on a 7.1-rc version

Answer (score 0):

Its Magento 2.2.4 default bug, you can edit the file code as given below. Please note that

```
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface;
```

is updated to

```
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface as LoggerConfigInterface;
```

and used accordingly.

```
<?php
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Payment\Model\Method;

use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface as LoggerConfigInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class Logger for payment related information (request, response, etc.) which is used for debug.
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Logger
{
    const DEBUG_KEYS_MASK = '****';

/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

/**
 * @var LoggerConfigInterface
 */
private $config;

/**
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param LoggerConfigInterface $config
 */
public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    LoggerConfigInterface $config = null
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->config = $config;
}

/**
     * Logs payment related information used for debug
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param array|null $maskKeys
     * @param bool|null $forceDebug
     * @return void
     */
    public function debug(array $data, array $maskKeys = null, $forceDebug = null)
    {
        $maskKeys = $maskKeys !== null ? $maskKeys : $this->getDebugReplaceFields();
        $debugOn = $forceDebug !== null ? $forceDebug : $this->isDebugOn();
        if ($debugOn === true) {
            $data = $this->filterDebugData(
                $data,
                $maskKeys
            );
            $this->logger->debug(var_export($data, true));
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns configured keys to be replaced with mask
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getDebugReplaceFields()
    {
        if ($this->config && $this->config->getValue('debugReplaceKeys')) {
            return explode(',', $this->config->getValue('debugReplaceKeys'));
        }
        return [];
    }
    /**
     * Whether debug is enabled in configuration
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isDebugOn()
    {
        return $this->config && (bool)$this->config->getValue('debug');
    }
    /**
     * Recursive filter data by private conventions
     *
     * @param array $debugData
     * @param array $debugReplacePrivateDataKeys
     * @return array
     */
    protected function filterDebugData(array $debugData, array $debugReplacePrivateDataKeys)
    {
        $debugReplacePrivateDataKeys = array_map('strtolower', $debugReplacePrivateDataKeys);
        foreach (array_keys($debugData) as $key) {
            if (in_array(strtolower($key), $debugReplacePrivateDataKeys)) {
                $debugData[$key] = self::DEBUG_KEYS_MASK;
            } elseif (is_array($debugData[$key])) {
                $debugData[$key] = $this->filterDebugData($debugData[$key], $debugReplacePrivateDataKeys);
            }
        }
        return $debugData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing Error --->
[2018-06-18 09:30:38] main.CRITICAL: Default website is not defined {"exception":"[object] (DomainException(code: 0): Default website is not defined at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\m224\\vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\WebsiteRepository.php:144)"} []